# Calling a function recursively in Python by passing a List

Tags: python, function, recursion

I know there are easier ways to create a function which gives you the largest number in a list of numbers but I wanted to use recursion. When I call the function greatest, i get none. For example greatest([1,3,2]) gives me none. If there are only two elements in the list, I get the right answer so I know the problem must be with the function calling itself. Not sure why though.

```
def compare(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return a
    if a > b:
        return a
    if a < b:
        return b


def greatest(x):
    if len(x)==0:
        return 0
    i=0
    new_list=[]
    while i< len(x):
        if len(x)-i>1:
            c=compare(x[i],x[i+1])
        else:
            c=x[i]
        new_list.append(c)
        i=i+2
    if len(new_list)>1:
        greatest(new_list)
    else:
        return new_list[0]

print greatest([1,3,2])
```

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for future posts.

Comment: thanks. any thoughts on the question?

Comment: This looks... _way_ overcomplicated.  `compare` can be replaced with the built-in `max`, and a recursion solution really shouldn't be looping over the list - just compare `x[0]` with `greatest(x[1:])`...

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
if len(new_list)>1:
    greatest(new_list) # <- this one here
```

calls `greatest` but doesn't do anything with the value it returns.  You want

```
    return greatest(new_list)
```

After fixing that, your function seems to behave (although I didn't look too closely):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     print i, all(max(g) == greatest(g) for g in itertools.product(range(-5, 5), repeat=i))
... 
1 True
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 True
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursion can be like this :

```
from random import *
def greatest(x,maxx=float("-inf")):
    if len(x)>0:
        if x[0] > maxx:
            maxx=x[0]
        return greatest(x[1:],maxx)
    else:
        return maxx

lis=range(10,50)
shuffle(lis)
print greatest(lis) #prints 49
```

Comment: You can simplify that by a couple lines like so: https://gist.github.com/meonkeys/5132023

Comment: you're welcome. Looks like there's an indent error now (`return maxx` should be left indented one tabstop).

Comment: @AdamMonsen No that will not raise `IndentationError`, but still fixed that.